# How do I calculate the value of a power series using the radius of convergence of another series?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

My power series is:

$$\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n(n-1)})x^n$$
Now I calculate the radius of convergence using the quotient criterion:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1-1)}x^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}x^n}|\rightarrow |x|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{n+1}\rightarrow |x|\cdot 1\rightarrow |x|<1\rightarrow radius\text{    } of\text{    } convergence\text{   r }=1$$

How can I use this to calculate the value of this series $$\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)3^n}$$ ?

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Just knowing convergence of a sum does not give information on its value.

Comment: The sum is a function $f(x)$ of $x$ -- look at the second derivative of that function.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)3^n}=\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n}\Big(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\Big)=\frac{1}{3}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{3^n}-\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{3}\,$. 

Next, use $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln(1-x)$ for $x<1$

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics. Use $\cdot$ (`$\cdot$`), $\times$ (`$\times$`) or just use juxtaposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider the following power series (known as geometric series) which converges whenever $|x| < 1$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} = 1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + \ldots = \frac{1}{1 - x}
\end{align*}

Then integrate it twice:
\begin{align*}
& \int_{0}^{x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{n}\right)\mathrm{d}y = x + \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} + \frac{x^{4}}{4} + \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}\\\\
& \int_{0}^{x}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n}}{n}\right)\mathrm{d}y = \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{2\times 3} + \frac{x^{4}}{3\times 4} + \frac{x^{5}}{4\times 5} + \ldots = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n(n-1)}
\end{align*}

Based on the provided suggestion, can you take it from here?